# Interface in Android

Tags: android, interface

I have written a table layout in android that contains image and video view.

I want to write an interface in android which will take the images as well as data and videos without disturbing my layout.

This data can come in any form and from any source and has to be supplied to the layout through the interface.

How should I write a program interface for the layout that I have developed in android?

Answer (score 0):

First you need two classes.

1. First class will behave as `Activity` in which You need to display the layout and implemented the interface or abstract class.
2. Second class will be responsible for fetching the data in background using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which will take object of interface as input in constructor and when task in this class in completed then it will update first class by calling the method of object of interface passed by first class by passing data.

Interface should be defined and implemented in `Activity` class and method of which will update the UI of first class.

Please let me know if u need some code help

Comment: yes if you have anykind of code related to it kindly provide, as i am confused. so i will be thankful if you will provide me the code. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code for CallBack Interface used in Android

```
public class BackGroundProcess
    {
    private RequestCallback mCallback;
    public BackGroundPrecess(RequestCallback ObjRequestCallback)
    {
    mCallback=ObjRequestCallback;
    }

    public void doBackgroundProcess()
    {
    /// perform action here
     onProcessComplete();

    }
    private void onProcessComplete(){
    mCallback.requestDidLoad(response);
    }
    }



    // activity class
    public class main_activity extends Activity{

    private void post_message()
        {
    BackGroundProcess obj=new BackGroundProcess(new MSRequestCallback());
    obj.doBackgroundProcess();

    }

    // Interface
    private class MSRequestCallback extends RequestCallback {

           public void requestDidFail(String page) {

                mHandler.post(mUpdate);  
           }

    }

    final Handler mHandler= new Handler();

       final Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              // update the UI
           }
       };
    }
```