# Implement Interface to Access data

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7858832/interface-in-android)

i want to implement a interface to access the data on demand by UI. the data must be hardcoded or from the Network . if anyone has done it kindly help .

Thanks in advance